# Screen Pinning & Incoming calls

Tags: android, incoming-call, android-screen-pinning

Is there a way to answer calls while my app is Screen pinned. I found theses informations online.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79260 - dated from a year ago - it seems that it's normal behavior of the screenPinning.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675657/how-can-i-call-stoplocktask-method-when-there-is-an-incoming-call - not enough reputation to answer or follow this post.

I use a broadcastReceiver to detect incoming calls. I can stoplocktask() in the broadcastReceiver but it's too late, the phone call seems to be killed at the same time the broadcastReceiver is called.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this method
[clearAbortBroadcast()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#clearAbortBroadcast())
at the end of the onReceive() in BroadcastReceiver.
This should propagate the event to other call receivers and therefore trigger default system call handler.